# setting a value through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

```
 <script>
function edit(elem)
{
var ele=$(elem).siblings('label#test').html();
var a=document.getElementById('test');
var htm = '<input type="text" name="modal" id="modal" style="width:70%;" value="'+$(elem).siblings('label#test').html();+'"/>';
$dialog.html(htm)
     .dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        position: 'center' ,
        title: 'EDIT',
        draggable: false,
        width : 300,
        height : 40,
        resizable : false,
        modal : true,

        buttons: { "Save" : function() { if($('#modal').val() != ''){a.value=$('#modal').val();$dialog.dialog('close');} else {alert('i++'+$('#modal').val()+'++');} } }
     });
$dialog.dialog('open');
  }


 $(document).ready(function() {
  var flag=0;

  $("input:radio[@name=template]").click(function() {
     var checkedoption = $(this).val();
     if (checkedoption == "template3")
     {
        if (flag == 0)
        {
           var html = '<input type="text" name="val" id="val" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Add" id="add"><br>';
           $('#useroptions').append(html);
           flag=1;

           $('#add').click(function(){
              var a = $('#val').val();
              if (a == '')
              {
                 alert('Enter options');
              }
              else
              {
                      var section= '<tr class="clickable"><td id="userval" BGCOLOR="#FF6699"><label id="test">' + a + '</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <IMG SRC="/media/img/chunkedit.gif" onclick="javascript:edit(this);" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<IMG SRC="/media/img/close.gif" onclick="javascript:remove(this);" ></td></tr>';
                  $('#useroptions').append(section);
              }
     });
     }
 }
});
});
</script>
<form>
<table>
       <tr><td>
<div id="useroptions"></div>
</tr></td>

</table>
 </form>
```

How to set a new value for test in the above code..
Thanks

Comment: The label element doesn't contain a form control and doesn't have a for attribute. Are you sure you're using it correctly? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Use the value overload like this:

```
$(elem).siblings('label#test').html("<span>new value</span>");
```

Comment: But it will change the old value in this case rit?

Comment: @Hulk, that's correct, can you describe more of what you're after?  I'm sure we can provide a better solution to your overall problem.

Comment: Hi,If i add 2 values say a and b and then set the html to the above said it will overide 'a' since 'a' was added first while i edited 'b'.Hot to deal this..

Comment: @Hulk - That would mean 2 siblings are present with ID `test`...that's invalid HTML.  If `a` and `b` are on different rows, that's ok, the `.siblings()` call won't leave the row.  However, the multiple ID issue would still be there, I recommend using a class instead.

Comment: @Hulk - Could you update your post with the table you're trying to edit?, it's easier to show you want to change than to guess your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can just refer to #test as id-s need to be unique and then set the value using text (or use html if you need to create html elements inside #test)

```
$('#test').text("new value");
```

Comment: But it will change the old value in this case rit?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite the old value. If you want to keep the old value, you have to store that somewhere.

Comment: Hi,If i add 2 values say a and b and then set the html to the above said it will overide a since a was added first while i edited b.Hot to deal this..
Hi,If i add 2 values say 'a' and 'b' and then set the html to the above said it will overide 'a' since 'a' was added first while i edited 'b'.Hot to deal this..